# hosting a windows game on a linux server

Tags: multiplayer, server, windows, unreal, linux

there! I am currently working on a game on Unreal 4, and although im still in early production(barely any code written, mostly visual assets at this point), i want to ask this now, so that i know how to organize my work schedule. If the game it self is running on windows, can the games multiplayer server be on a linux machine? If possible will there be any complications during coding or setup that i need to look into? would very much apreciate any help. :)

Comment: Yes you can; the biggest issue will be data encoding and decoding (endiannes and stuff).

Comment: if you know where i could read in to this subject a bit more thoroughly, that would be nice :)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Endianess should not be a problem between Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Philipp I'll take your word for it; never tried it. My point was more that there was some details to take into consideration :)

Comment: As was mentioned this is very possible. It's more of a networking problem than a game problem however. I'd recommend researching TCP/IP and TCP vs UDP and then writing some more basic networking applications. Try writing a basic Linux server in C or Java or whatever and then a simple client on Windows (java is probably easiest for this). Try sending data back and forth. I can guarantee you'll run into a problem with strings at some point. Windows doesn't support UTF-8 (for display and output) and Linux defaults to UTF-8 so you'll need to decide what to do about that.